# enter key + control key press to create new line in textarea not working in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, textarea, caret

I am trying to produce control key and enter key keypress to put new line in textarea. Works great in chrome, firefox but not ie9. I searched a bit and turns out that there is issue of carriage return or sth like that with IE rendering new line. I am able to move the cursor to new line but when i start typing it start at the earlier line instead.

sample of code is like:

```
var beforeCursor = base.$el.val().substr(0,pos.start);
var afterCursor = base.$el.val().substr(pos.start,base.$el.val().length);
    base.$el.val(beforeCursor +"\n"+afterCursor);
    base.$el.caret(beforeCursor.length+1, beforeCursor.length+1);
```

any help or link to probable help whould be nice. Thanks in advance.